# passing variables to a process from linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, keystroke

I want to make a program that will gather information about the keystrokes of a user (keycode, press and release times) and will use them as a biometric for authenticating the user continuously. My approach is to gather the keystrokes using a kernel module (because you can't just kill a kernel module), than the kernel module will send the information to another process that will analyze the data gathered by the kernel module, it will save it to a database and will return an answer to the kernel (the user is authenticated or not) and the kernel will lock the computer if the user is not authenticated. the whole module will not be distributed.

my questions are:
  1. How can I call a process from the kernel and also send him the data?
  2. how can I return a message to the kernel from the process?

Comment: Are you sure to have legal permission to do that? What is the concrete motivation and use case? You should state them in your question, so **edit your question** to give a lot more details.

Comment: In its current form, the question is unclear and cannot be answered. I'm voting to close it. I see no reason for kernel code.

Comment: Is this a school project, a software for some new hardware, a PhD work? Is your goal to make simple experimentation for research, or to make a reliable product? You need to give even more context and motivation, and you should tell the real use case (which probably involves X11 or Wayland)...

Comment: I am quite sure you don't need to write a single line of kernel code. But you are confused and should spend weeks in reading. I suspect you need to hack the X11 server or some window manager, or something related to Wayland.

Comment: If this is a school or a research project: first, read the books mentioned in my answer. Then, focus on your particular display server (and learning X11 can take many months and you'll need to read several thousands of pages).

Comment: I started a chat with you. Please join it. I will close the chat in ten minutes if you don't join it.

Comment: Your question is perfectly fine even though  you have not actually attempted to research it. See my answer on how to approach it. If you have questions on specific technical methods elaborate.

Answer (score 2):

@basile-starynkevitch 's answer and his arguments notwithstanding there *is* an approach you can take that is perfectly correct and technically allowed by the linux kernel.

Register a keyboard notifier call back function using the kernel call `register_keyboard_notifier()` in your kernel module. As a matter of fact it's designed for exactly this!

Your notifier call back function will look something like:

```
int keysniffer_callback(struct notifier_block *notifier_block,
          unsigned long scancode,
          void *param) 
{
    // do something with the scancode

    return NOTIFY_OK; 
}
```

See https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/notifier.txt for starters.

Comment: Maybe you should also explain how this can be used to e.g. alter the keypresses, e.g. swap scancode 34 and 35. The documentation is not clear enough about that

Comment: Then you should explain how a kernel driver will fill an existing database. I'm also interested (and impatient) in that aspect. Please explain what kind of database do you consider using. Give concrete advices, usable by a kernel newbie like me.

Comment: Happy to. May take some time 

Answer (score 0):

> I want to make a program that will gather information about the keystrokes of a user

That should go in practice into your [display server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_server), which you did not mention ([Xorg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.Org_Server), [Wayland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_(display_server_protocol)), [MIR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mir_(software)), ...?). Details matter a big lot!

> My approach is to gather the keystrokes using a kernel module

I strongly believe this is a wrong approach, **you don't need any kernel module**.

> I want to make a program that gathers data about the user keystrokes

Then use ordinary Unix machinery. The keyboard is some [character device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file#Character_devices) (and you could have several keyboards, or none, or some virtual one...) and you could [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) from it. If you want to code a [keylogger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystroke_logging), please tell that explicitly.

<sup>(be aware that a keylogger or any other cyberspying activity can be illegal when used without consent and without permission; in most countries, that could send you to jail: in France, [Article 323-1 du Code Pénal](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCodeArticle.do?idArticle=LEGIARTI000006418316&cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006070719) punishes that by at least 2 years of jail; and most other countries have similar laws)</sup>

> the kernel module will send the information to another process [....] it will save it to a database

This is practically very difficult to get (and you look confused). Databases are in user-land (e.g. some [RDBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) like PostGresSQL, or some library accessing files like [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/)). Notice that a kernel driver cannot (easily and reliably) even access to files.

All application programs (and most daemons & servers) on Linux are started with [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) (e.g. by some [unix shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) process, or by some daemon, etc...), and I see no reason for you to make an exception. However, some programs (mostly [`init`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init), but also a few others, e.g. `/sbin/hotplug`) are started by the kernel, but this is exceptional (and should be avoided, and you don't need that).

> 1. How can I call a process from the kernel

You should not do that. I see no reason for your program to avoid being started by `execve` from some other process (perhaps your `init`, e.g. [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd)).

> and also send him the data?

Your process, as all other processes, is interacting with the kernel thru [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) (listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)). So your application program could use [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html), [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html), [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) etc.. Be aware of [netlink(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netlink.7.html).

> 2. how can I return a message to the kernel from the process?

You don't. Use system calls, initiated by application code.

> the kernel will lock the computer if the user is not authenticated.

This does not have any sense. [Screen locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_screen) is a GUI artefact (so is *not* done by kernel code, but by ad-hoc daemon processes). Of course some processes do continue to run when locking is enabled. And many processes are [daemons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing)) or [servers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_(computing)) which don't belong to "the" user (and continue to run when "the computer is locked"). At heart, Linux & POSIX is a [multi-user](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-user) and [multi-tasking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_multitasking) operating system. Even on a desktop Linux system used by a single physical person, you have dozens of users (i.e. [uid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_identifier)-s many of them specialized to a particular feature, look into your `/etc/passwd` file, see [passwd(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/passwd.5.html)) and more than a hundred processes (each having its [pid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier)), use [top(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html) or [ps(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html) as `ps auxw` to list them.

---

I believe you have the **wrong approach**. Take first several days or weeks to understand more about Linux from the application point of view. So read some book about Linux programming, e.g. [ALP](http://www.cse.hcmut.edu.vn/~hungnq/courses/nap/alp.pdf) or something newer. Read also something like: [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/)

Be aware that in practice, most Linux systems having a [desktop environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment) are using some [display server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_server). So the (physical) keyboard is handled by the [X11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) or [Wayland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_(display_server_protocol)) server. You need to read more about your display server (with X11, things like [EWMH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Window_Manager_Hints)).

Hence, you need to be much more specific. You are likely to need to interact with the display server, not the kernel directly.

At last, a rule of thumb is to avoid bloating your kernel with extra and useless driver code. You very probably can do your thing in userland entirely.

So, **spend a week** or more **reading** about OSes & Linux before coding a single line of code. Avoid kernel modules, they will bite you, and you probably don't need them (but you might need to hack your display server or simply your [window manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_manager); of course details are different with X11 and with Wayland). Read also about [multiseat](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/multiseat/) Linux systems.

At last, most Linux distributions are made of [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), whose source code you can study. So take time to look into the source code of relevant software for your (ill-defined) goals. Use also [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to understand the system calls dynamically done by commands and processes.

Comment: I am making a keylogger, the problem I have is that i want to analyze the data and to save the results to a file, stuff that i heard, not recommended to do from the kernel space.

Comment: I believe you got it wrong. And details are quite system specific. Most systems are using a display server, and you'll better interact with it. That display server is an application program (perhaps [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid)). BTW, why can't you use or enhance some existing keylogger? At last, be aware of the legal issues (in most countries, running a keylogger without explicit approval and permission can send you to jail).

Comment: The point of the whole kernel module is that it is using Keystroke dynamics as a biometric for authentication. I want that the program will be able to gather information from any key the user types and that it won't be easy to just kill the process, that is why i am using a kernel module.

Comment: That should go into the question, and I don't see why it should be a kernel module. IMHO it should *not* be kernel code at all. But you need to give a lot more details, by editing your question. Before that, spend several days in reading more, you look very confused (and I won't trust your driver)

Comment: can you reference some articles or tutorials on how to hack x11 or wayland?

Comment: No, but both are free software. You'll need several months or years of work. For a proof-of-concept approach you could even restrict yourself to a particular GUI [widget toolkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget_toolkit) like [Qt](http://qt.io/) or [GTK](http://gtk.org/). BTW hacking or [cybercrime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cybercrime) is illegal, including in Israel, so I strongly recommend not doing that. Patching or contributing to some free software project is entirely different. Each community has its own way of working, and many of them are helpful.

Comment: I'm waiting for you to join the chat. Will stop in ten minutes if you don't.

Comment: actually this answer is not quite as accurate as it can be :P

Comment: To elaborate, there's a lot of unnecessary commentary about what's legal and what's not in this answer that IMHO has *no* place in a technical discussion. OP is responsible for her own actions, and solving a technical problem has nothing to do with whether or not it's legally allowed under some jurisdiction which is beyond the scope of the OP's question. And technically speaking this answer is incorrect because the linux kernel actually *does* have a stable API for modules that want to trap keyboard notifications!

Comment: @AhmedMasud: I certainly won't let my technical answer make someone believe that what is technically possible is legally permitted. Of course, feel free to explain (even to me) what is the stable kernel API for keyboard modules. I don't know it; so please provide your own informed answer.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch please see https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/notifier.txt

Comment: See also my last comment to your very interesting answer